# How should i import the sass files in angular

Tags: angular, sass

For example, I have scss files structure like below:

```
src
 | - assets
        |
        | - scss
             |
             | - patials
                    | - _variable.scss
                    | - _flex--layout.scss
                    | - _button.scss
```

And all the partials have been imported in the styles.scss:

**styles.scss**

```
@import 'app/styles/normalize';
@import 'app/styles/variables';
@import 'assets/scss/_loading';
@import 'assets/scss/partials/_color.vars';
@import 'assets/scss/partials/size.vars';
@import 'assets/scss/partials/utils';
```

Question:
If a component used both _variable.scss, _flex--layout.scss and _button.scss in its xxx.componenet.scss,
should i @import the styles.scss once,

```
@import '../../../styles.scss';
```

or I should import all the partials needed like below:

```
@import '../../../assets/scss/partials/_color.vars';
@import '../../../assets/scss/partials/size.vars';
@import '../../../assets/scss/partials/utils';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this - > Go to `style.scss` and `import`

```
@import '../src/assets/scss/patials/_variable.scs';
@import '../src/assets/scss/patials/_flex--layout.scss';
@import '../src/assets/scss/patials/_button.scss';
```

ANS - Only Import In `style.scss` effect all over `project`

Answer (score 1):

```
@import '../../../styles.scss';
```

This should be enough.